# How to use custom log4j.properties accessible via hdfs file with dcos Spark

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, hdfs, mesos, dcos

I am trying to pass a custom log4j.properties file located in `hdfs` to a `spark` job launched with the `dcos` cli. I have tried any possible permutation of available spark configuration options (e.g. `--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=‘-Dlog4j.configuration=hdfs://conf/custom-log4j.properties’`) but there is no way to make it work, the configuration is just ignored.

Comment: You should host properties file in web server add add that in dcos-cli.

Comment: thank you @WoodChopper, is that because hdfs is not accessible by spark-submit or because of something else? I am already passing other configuration parameters (e.g., spark.mesos.uris) that are located on hdfs and it works just fine. I would avoid to spin up a web server if not strictly necessary.